# Use canvas drawImage to separate img into two halves

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to split image in my canvas. 
First I'm declaring canvas in HTML:

```
<canvas width="600" height="400" id="canvas_1">
        Canvas tag not supported
</canvas>
```

Then I'm unsuccesfully spliting my image:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_1");

if (canvas.getContext){
   var canvas_context = canvas.getContext("2d");
   var img = document.getElementById("london_eye");
   canvas_context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 230, 300, 20, 20, 80, 300);
   canvas_context.drawImage(img, 30, 0, 180, 300, 200, 20, 80, 300);
}
```

I guess I'm missing something there..

```
canvas_context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 230, 300, 20, 20, 80, 300);
canvas_context.drawImage(img, 30, 0, 180, 300, 200, 20, 80, 300);
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bimbochobot/fokzwyew/)
Thank you for your time and advices

Comment: Your image is 120x120 pixels and you're trying to fetch pixels beyond the image size in your drawImages (trying to fetch 230x300 pixels in your first draw and 180x300 in your second draw). Take another look at [how context.drawImage works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage). :-)

Comment: @markE Hehe, yeah just tried about everything but it's near to impossible in this case.

Comment: @markE but it doesn't work even when I make it like 230x300 -> 120x120 and 180x300 -> 120x120 pixels

Comment: [Or...](https://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/n0z6j07r/). :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Original Code**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_1");

if (canvas.getContext){
  var canvas_context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var img = document.getElementById("london_eye");
  canvas_context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 60, 120, 0, 0, 60, 120);
  canvas_context.drawImage(img, 60, 0, 60, 120, 70, 0, 60, 120);
}
```

[image: pieces of image]

The last four parameters are destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight. So this is where on the canvas you want to put these pieces, you can see second piece is at 70 so its width of first piece 60 plus gap of 10.

*I put a gap of 10px to show the two pieces of your img in the snippet!*

```js
var i = new Image();
i.crossOrigin = '';
i.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_1");
    
    if (canvas.getContext){
      var canvas_context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      canvas_context.drawImage(i, 0, 0, 60, 120, 0, 0, 60, 120);
      canvas_context.drawImage(i, 60, 0, 60, 120, 70, 0, 60, 120);
    }
};
i.onerror = function() {
    i.src = 'http://cors.io?u=' + i.src;
    i.onerror = function() {
        document.write('Error loading image');
    }
};
i.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/olfBw.png';
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas_1"></canvas>
```